# Passing variables through parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, parameters, xmlhttprequest

Here I have a block of code that I've been debugging over Firebug. I want to know how I can pass my parameter `foo` into the function `getHoliday(param,param,param)`. Here is the block of code from my XMLHttpRequest.

```
if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState==4 && XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
{
    var pp = null
    var dd = null
    var xmlResponse = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;
    var foo = new Array();
    foo = parseXML(xmlResponse);
    getHoliday(pp,dd,foo);
}
```

The first two parameters of `getHoliday` are un-used until later in the process. I want to first load `getHoliday` with data from the array `foo` so in the future I can use foo as shown below. As soon as my break point arrives at getHoliday, the script stops so I believe it's the parameters that are wrong. I want to point out, `pp` and `dd` are nothing, just place holders for empty undefined parameter.

```
function getHoliday(monthSelected,theday,names)
{   
    var HolidayName = new Array();
    var holiday = ""
    HolidayName = names;  
    monthSelected = monthSelected + 1;
    for(var index = 0; HolidayName.length >= index; index++)
    {   
        if(HolidayName[index] == monthSelected && HolidayName[index+1] == theday)
        {
            holiday = HolidayName[index+2]
        }
    }
    return holiday
}
```

As soon as my gets down here, `names` array that I just passed becomes undefined. Why? Below is how `HolidayName` array should look.

```
HolidayName = new Array(2,4,"Party--12:00",2,22,"Eventalist Launch--6:00",2,18,"Play Day--12:00",3,17,"Play Day--12:00"););
```

When alerting `foo` the result is:

```
2,4,"Party--12:00",2,22,"Eventalist Launch--6:00",2,18,"Play Day--12:00",3,17,"Play Day--12:00"
```

Here is parseXML

```
function parseXML(xmlData)
{
    var aOutput=document.getElementById("testing2");
    var events = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('year').length;
    for(var i=0;i< events;i++)
    {
        var eYear = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('year')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var eMonth = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('month')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var eDay = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('day')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var eHour = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('hours')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var eMinute = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('minutes')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var eTitle = xmlData.getElementsByTagName('title')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var holiStr = '"' + eTitle + "--" + eHour  +":"+ eMinute + '"';
        setup.push(eMonth,eDay, holiStr);
    }
    return setup;
}
```

Comment: `xhro.responseXML` is an XML Document Object already, you hardly will need to parse it. Please show us what that `parseXML` does, it seems to return `undefined`

Comment: alerting foo where gets that result?

Comment: Btw, in javascript you cannot declare variable types. All those `= new Array()` calls are senseless.

Comment: Yes my foo is alright. Its exactly what I need.

Comment: I'm very confused by your question .. what is the problem exactly?

Comment: @GivenPie no.  are you alerting foo in the if block or the getHoliday block?

Comment: When I pass the array foo, it ends up becoming undefined in `getHoliday` function. Its not suppose to do that since I am able to display all elements of `foo` from responseXML. I am alerting `names` actaully, down in `getHoliday` function.

Comment: @GivenPie Try using `console.log(names)` or `alert(JSON.stringify(names))` at the beginning of the `getHoliday` function. Is `names` undefined?

Comment: What is `setup`? It is initialised nowhere.

Comment: by the way, this would all be much easier to debug if you set up a jsfiddle

Comment: Wow you really named your XHR instance `XMLHttpRequestObject`? That's unusual =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the information you have provided, best guess: do you have var foo lower in the code? Javascript does not have block level scoping and these get hoisted to the top of functions and  var foo lower could alter your foo value.